# How to add default value to hyperlink field type

Tags: 2010, column, hyperlink

I've created a custom list and added one column of type hyperlink.

How can i change the default value (http://) into another value? Is this possible?

Comment: Please stop using your signature :)

Answer (score 1):

Natively there isn't a way to use a default value with a hyperlink field. A singline line of text coulmn might work, but depending on the URL you might hit the 255 character limit. You could use some javascript/jQuery to set a URL and description by default.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Single Line of text and have the Default value what you need it. You would be losing the formatting feature though.

You can also probably try to create a custom column type

Answer (score 0):

You can try Eventhandlers ItemAdding/ItemUpdating for changing the default values.

Comment: Would you please care to provide a bit more detail? The OP may just refer to the GUI. What do they need to implement your suggestion?

Comment: properties.AfterProperties["Fieldname"] can be used to set the values at the time of creation. However, if the GUI needs to be updated at the time of opening the page (e.g. newform.aspx) then things like SPServices, JQuery can be used to include client side code to update the field.